# How to modify SEO Paging of RadGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, paging, radgrid

I have a page with

- 2 textbox : ID is txt1 and txt2
- 1 RadGrid : ID rgTest

i using Simple Paging for "rgTest" and set EnableSEOPaging=True

Each times i change page of "rgTest" i get URL like :

```
http://localhost:9526/Default.aspx?rgTestChangePage=5
```

My question is :

- How to change the name of QueryString : "rgTestChangePage" -> MyPage
- How to add params in QueryString like that:

  Default.aspx?rgTestChangePage=5&&param1=txt1&&param2=txt2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SEOPagingQueryStringKey property : http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-seo-paging.html

To add your own parameters - there are many ways to modify an URL, just make sure you don't break it. Try googling for a bit in your preferred language (C#, VB or JavaScript) to find sample snippets that will parse an URL and let you append params.